# Reading and Labelling the folders

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to read the folders of my dataset but the program is reading only 1st folder and not the rest.**Can someone tell how to loop on those folders and label those folders side by side?** 
the program is as below:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import glob
    import numpy as np
    #%%
    path=glob.glob('C:/Users/HP/Documents/Trying
                    /Devanagari_character_dataset/consonants/*/')
    #%%
    label=[]
    img_list=[]
    k=0

    for i, file in enumerate(path):
        file=glob.glob(path[k]+'/*')
        img_list=plt.imread(file)
        k +=1
        label.append(i)
```

Comment: `img_list=[]`, but then you overwrite instead of append

Answer (score 0):

[os.walk()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) offers more flexibility for traversal of paths and can help you locate directory/folder names:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```